# Updating spring boot application configuration at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have implemented shutdown API in my spring-boot project by setting following values in application.properties:

```
 management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
 management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
 management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Now I want to disable the shutdown API dynamically with help of database like I will have those above configurations as key, value pair that I can change anytime.

On its change, *the application should get also updated with the new config values* thereby ***shutdown API gets disabled***.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ***Netflix Archaius***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You don't need to use `@Value` annotation here.

**Usage**

```
DynamicStringProperty dynamicProperty = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getStringProperty("management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled", "default value here");
String propertyCurrentValue = dynamicProperty.get();
```

If the data changes in property file at any point, Archaius will detect it at runtime and will start retrieving the new values.

**Useful references**

- [Archaius Girhub info](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius)
- [Archaius with Various Database Configurations](https://www.baeldung.com/netflix-archaius-database-configurations)
- [Archaius for Property Management - Basics](https://dzone.com/articles/netflix-archaius-property)

Comment: I tried this approach. However, it didn't work. Here is [source code](https://github.com/nazar-art/archaius-demo). When you start app you could access `http://localhost:8080/properties-from-dynamic`. Check the result. Now update some property at `config.properties`. And check again - no difference. So for this case storing to DB is the most reasonable solution.